# How to give two messages to a single toast using react-toastify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-toastify

I wanted to display a toast message when user clicked on favorite button, the message should be either Added to Fav or removed From Fav, but I want only a single toast to do it. Is it possible?
If yes then how to implement it.

I am able to display two toast with two different toast messages

Comment: Can you give a minimal example how you instantiate your toast -message?

Answer (score 0):

You can usa a custom component that will be displayed as your toast. See the documentation of react-toastify: https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/render-what-you-want

By doing that you can put as much messages into one toast as you like.